# Regex split on words unless in quotes or brackets

Tags: regex, perl

How do I split the following using Regex

```
words and [other word] combined with "words in quotes"
```

The output should be split as:

```
words
and
other word
combined
with
words in quotes
```

Thanks!

(Answers do not have to be in perl but in general regex format is fine.)

Comment: Can the brackets ever be nested? Can they be `<>`, `()`, or `{}` instead?

Comment: No the brackets are only []

Comment: Please show the Perl code that you are having a problem with

Comment: What result do you want from the string `words ]and [other "combined [ with "words`?

Comment: I can split the brackets using: 
    \s+(?![^\[]*\])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$string = 'words and [other word] combined with "words in quotes"';
while($string =~ /(?|\[([^]]*)]|"([^"]*)"|(\w+))/g) {
    print $1 . "\n";
}
```

I use the [branch reset](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) feature `(?|...|...|...)` to give the three capturing groups the same number.

Comment: Worth breaking into chunks and explaining, perhaps?

Comment: @Casimir I get this error `Sequence (?|...) not recognized in regex; marked by <--...`. Any idea?

Comment: -1 for an overly-specific answer that could have been hard-coded

Comment: @SabujHassan: where are you testing the pattern?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I am using `Perl v5.8.8`. Also this link seems can not explain your regex using Perl `YAPE`: http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl

Comment: Thanks @CasimiretHippolyte for the update. Its nice to know this feature. I didn't know about it. Its introduced since Perl 5.10. Looks like I am still living in the old days! :-P

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Why are you using `\w`? This doesn't seem to be program text. It means your solution splits every word onto a separate line, which makes nonsense of the brackets and quotes. You have written `print "$_\n" for $string =~ /(\w+)/g` in a very long-winded way.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have came up with:

```
my $str = 'words and [other word] combined with "words in quotes"';
my @arr = $str =~ /"([^"]*)"|\[([^\]]*)\]|(\S+)/g;

## removing undefined and empty things from array
@arr = grep { defined } @arr;

## printing array
$\ = $/;
print for @arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you ask isn't simple, and I wish you had answered my questions.

Given the very limited information, my guess is that this is close what you want.

It's relatively complicated and uses the alternation reset pattern that has been available only since Perl 5 version 10.

I have written a solution that removes any balanced brackets and double quotes, but leaves all spaces intact. If any opening brackets or quotes aren't matched with a closing delimiter then no more of the string is processed.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $s = 'words and [other word] combined with "words in quotes"';

my @tokens;

while ( $s =~ / \G (?| \[ ( [^\[\]]* ) \] | " ( [^"]* ) " | ( [^\[\]"]+ ) ) /gx ) {
  print "«$1»\n";
}
```

**output**

```
«words and »
«other word»
« combined with »
«words in quotes»
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit verbose, but is reasonably clear:

```
   ^[a-zA-Z]*\w|(?<=([\b\s]))[a-z]*(?=[\b\s])|(?<=\[)(.*)(?=\])|(?<=")(.*)(?=")
```